# Characterization of log-concavity based on the MGF or characteristic function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request

Is there any characterization of log-concavity (of probability distributions) in terms of the moment-generating function or characteristic function?

Specifically, I want to prove some random variable (real-valued) has a log-concave distribution. However, finding the pdf is a mess; but the MGF $M_X$ of $X$ is rather nice. Is there some property of $M_X$ which would imply log-concavity of (the distribution of) $X$?

Comment: What is the MGF you have?

Comment: The pdf is the inverse laplace transform of the MGF, yes?

Comment: @phdmba7of12 Yes, but is there any way to show log-concavity **without** getting the pdf? (As I mentioned, the pdf is actually messy. But even then, I'm interested in the question "is there a simple way to show log-concavity based on some 'natural and simple' property of the MGF, without going through the pdf")